# Scrapy LinkExtractor crawling links that use parent directory

Tags: python, scrapy

Using a basic [CrawlerSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) in Scrapy, I'm trying to crawl a page. The related links in the page that I want to crawl all start with the parent directory notation `..` instead of the full domain.

For example, if I'm starting with page `https://www.mytarget.com/posts/4/friendly-url`, and I want to crawl every post in `/posts`, the related links on that page will be:

```
'../55/post-name'
'../563/another-name'
```

instead of:

```
'posts/55/post-name'
'posts/563/another-name'
```

or what would be better:

```
'https://www.mytarget.com/posts/55/post-name'
'https://www.mytarget.com/posts/563/another-name'
```

Removing `mytarget.com` from `allowed_domains` doesn't seem to help. The crawler won't find new links on the website that match the `..` parent directory link reference.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from exercise_data_collector.items import Post

class MyCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['mytarget.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.mytarget.com/posts/4/friendly-url']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'posts/[0-9]+/[0-9A-Za-z-_]+'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/posts\/[0-9]+\/[0-9A-Za-z-_]+'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/..\/[0-9]+\/[0-9A-Za-z-_]+'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)

        item = Post()
        item["page_title"] = response.xpath('//title/text()').get()
        item["name"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[1]/div[1]/text()[2]").get().replace('->','').strip()
        item['difficulty'] = response.xpath("//p[strong[contains(text(), 'Difficulty')]]/text()").get().strip()

        return item
```

I'm not sure exactly how to configure the regex to get the related links or to even test if the regex is working outside of `regexr.com`.

How can I crawl pages like this?

Comment: The problem with `r'/..\/[0-9]+\/[0-9A-Za-z-_]+'` is the initial `/`, `r'..\/[0-9]+\/[0-9A-Za-z-_]+'` works in https://regex101.com/ (an online regex debugged that supports Python regex, unline regexr.com). Note: You can replace `\/` with `/`, `/` does not need escaping in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with this regex `r'posts/[0-9]+/[A-Za-z-_]+'`

```
class MyCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['mytarget.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.mytarget.com/posts/4/friendly-url']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'exercises/[0-9]+/[A-Za-z-_]+'), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    )
    def parse(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)

        item = Post()
        item["page_title"] = response.xpath('//title/text()').get()
        item["name"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[1]/div[1]/text()[2]").get().replace('->','').strip()
        item['difficulty'] = response.xpath("//p[strong[contains(text(), 'Difficulty')]]/text()").get().strip()

        return item
```

I did run into a recursive issue where `posts/12/page.html` changed to `posts/12/12/page.html` ... `posts/12/12/12/12/12/12/page.html`. I think this might have been an error on their site.